# AWS ECS how to execute aws-ecs-tools-defaults.json file

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecs, docker-image, docker-command

In visual studio 2017, it generates `aws-ecs-tools-defaults.json` file after image is published first time to AWS ECS.
I wonder is there any aws CLI or docker command to run this file. I know I do it from visual studio again but command line should be better.

Anyone tried?

Comment: can you provide `aws-ecs-tools-defaults.json` file?

Answer (score 1):

That file holds the metadata for the project build for .NET applications with Visual Studio. So you cannot build out or deploy your app with the cli by passing this file.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to dotnet https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli then run `dotnet ecs push-image`